# What is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, notation

I do not know what it is.

$\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers.

How come $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times \ldots $?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the set of all functions $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$. In general $X^Y$ is the set of all functions $Y\rightarrow X$.

Comment: Thanks. So it is a simple notation. I was confused with $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @det You should think of it as a straight generalization of this notation. A function from from $Y$ to $X$ can be thought of as a "tuple" of length $Y$, all of whose entries are elements of $X$.

Comment: @det: $\mathbf{R}^n$ can be thought of as the same way; if you interpret it as a von Neumann ordinal $n = \{ 0, 1, \ldots, n-1 \}$.

Comment: Yes got it. Thank you all very much.