# What does $\mathbb{R}^J$ mean?

Tags: real-numbers

Let J be some index set.

I was watching a lecture by Mikhail Gromov and he made a passing comment about why $\mathbb{R}^J$ makes sense because J is a set, but $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not because $n$ is a number.

I thought we just used $n$ because it was a convenient way of saying we are taking $n$ Cartesian products of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself.

Can some explain what this means?

Comment: See this [What is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753685/what-is-mathbbr-mathbbr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A,B$ are sets, one often writes $A^B$ for the set of all functions $B\to A$.
Some motivation for this may be that $A^B$ has $a^b$ elements if $A$ ahas $a$ and $B$ has $b$ elements. In a way you again take $|B|$ cartesian products of $A$ with itself, but for infinite $B$ this mental image breaks down.

You can view $\mathbb R^n$ as a special case of this if you identify $n$ with a standard $n$-element set such as $\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$.

Comment: So if we could talk about this in more detail... The definition is just a definition and that is fine (also I have seen it before). So let me make sure I understand. We have $$\mathbb{R}^J := \{ f : J \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \; | \; f \; \text{a function} \}$$ So for $J = \{ 0 , \cdots ,n \}$, the number of functions from $J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$? I am not understanding fully. Since $|\mathbb{R}| = c$ and $c^n = c$ (just using some naive set theory, I think maybe wrong).

Comment: @Actually, you should take $J=\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ or $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. A function from an $n$-element set is just a list (of length $n$) of values, so not much different from an $n$-tuple. The cardinality of $\mathbb R^n$ happens to be the same as that of $\mathbb R$, but that is not the main point - the finite case is the motivation only.

Comment: I meant $J = \{ 0, \cdots , n-1 \}$ just a typo, but thank you I am starting to understand

Answer (score 4):

This is a symbol for the family of all functions defined on $J$, taking values in $\mathbb{R}$. Technically, you can consider $n$-tuples or real numbers as functions defined on $\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$ which take values in $\mathbb{R}$.

This is a special case of a [Cartesian product of sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Comment: I would rather call it a symbol of the **set** of all **families** in $\mathbb{R}$
that are indexed by $J$. This in the sense that a **family** in $\mathbb{R}$
indexed by $J$ is exactly a **function** defined on $J$ (domain) and
taking values in $\mathbb{R}$ (codomain). In my view the symbol $\mathbb{R}^{J}$
is not the symbol for a **family**. Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/35462/75923